# How to debug a loop/moving forward in loop? (VBA)

Tags: vba, excel, loops, debugging, breakpoints

I'm trying to debug a multi-layered loop in VBA. I want to see the step-by-step process of the loop, but only well into the loop. (ie, the loop goes from 1 to 120, I would like to see it run when i = 110)

I know I can use the F8 key in break mode, but is there a way to advance through the loop without holding down the F8 key until I get to the point in the loop I need?

Thanks

Comment: start your loop at 120? Or set a break on value watch... or even If i = 120 Then STOP ....

Comment: There are different types of loops, and different ways you could have them "layered" (I think you mean *nested*).  Can't say for sure what you can do without knowing what you have.  (See "[mcve]")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just some options:

1. Add a watch and break on value (have to target correct value)
2. Start relevant loop at 110
3. Add `If` clause with `STOP` in the relevant loop; to name but a few.

Example with `If` clause:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub test()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 120
        If i = 110 Then
            Debug.Print i
            Stop
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood this correctly, perhaps you could do this:

```
Sub loop120()
Dim i As Integer

i = 0
Do
i = i + 1

    If i = 110 Then
        'Code goes here for when the loop has executed 120 times
        MsgBox "This is the 110th loop"
        '<---- stick a break point on your next line of code
    End If


Loop

End Sub
```

This way, you'll get the message box indicating the 110th loop. When you press ok your code will hit the break point and you'll be able to step through.